# Javascript implementing multiple countdown timers in a table

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have tried to create multiple countdown timers in a table that will rely on variables to set its time left. Currently there are no results output to the page and I'm not sure why.

Ideally, this should display 4 countdown timers

```js
var table;
table = ("<table>");
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    table += ("<tr>");
    table += ("<td> Time Left : </td>");
    table += ("<td><div id=\"dday" + i + "\"></div></td>");
    table += ("<td><div id=\"dhour" + i + "\"></div></td>");
    table += ("<td><div id=\"dmin" + i + "\"></div></td>");
    table += ("<td><div id=\"dsec" + i + "\"></div></td>");
    table += ("</tr>");
}
table += ("</table>");
document.getElementById('listinglist').innerHTML = table;
var yr = 2016,
    m = 2,
    d = 3,
    hr = 4,
    min = 5;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min, i);
}


var year = 2010; 
var month = 12; 
var day = 21; 
var hour = 18; 
var minute = 38; 
var tz = -5;
var montharray = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

function countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min) {
    theyear = yr;
    themonth = m;
    theday = d;
    thehour = hr;
    theminute = min;
    var today = new Date();
    var todayy = today.getYear();
    if (todayy < 1000) {
        todayy += 1900;
    }
    var todaym = today.getMonth();
    var todayd = today.getDate();
    var todayh = today.getHours();
    var todaymin = today.getMinutes();
    var todaysec = today.getSeconds();
    var todaystring1 = montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy + " " + todayh + ":" + todaymin + ":" + todaysec;
    var todaystring = Date.parse(todaystring1) + (tz * 1000 * 60 * 60);
    var futurestring1 = (montharray[m - 1] + " " + d + ", " + yr + " " + hr + ":" + min);
    var futurestring = Date.parse(futurestring1) - (today.getTimezoneOffset() * (1000 * 60));
    var dd = futurestring - todaystring;
    var dday = Math.floor(dd / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1);
    var dhour = Math.floor((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 1000) * 1);
    var dmin = Math.floor(((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
    var dsec = Math.floor((((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);
    document.getElementById('dday').innerHTML = dday;
    document.getElementById('dhour').innerHTML = dhour;
    document.getElementById('dmin').innerHTML = dmin;
    document.getElementById('dsec').innerHTML = dsec;
    setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,thehour,theminute)", 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="listinglist"></div>
```

Comment: One too many curly braces at the end? Open up your browser's console and see what errors appear.

Comment: It shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null on document.getElementById('dday').innerHTML = dday;

Comment: It shows the time left now. However the rest aren't being shown for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems in your script, like you are calling the count down function before the `montharray` is created, you are not using the `i` part in `getElementById` etc

```js
var table;
table = ("<table>");
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  table += ("<tr>");
  table += ("<td> Time Left : </td>");
  table += ("<td><div id=\"dday" + i + "\"></div></td>");
  table += ("<td><div id=\"dhour" + i + "\"></div></td>");
  table += ("<td><div id=\"dmin" + i + "\"></div></td>");
  table += ("<td><div id=\"dsec" + i + "\"></div></td>");
  table += ("</tr>");
}
table += ("</table>");
document.getElementById('listinglist').innerHTML = table;
var yr = 2016,
  m = 2,
  d = 3,
  hr = 4,
  min = 5;

var year = 2010;
var month = 12;
var day = 21;
var hour = 18;
var minute = 38;
var tz = -5;
var montharray = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

//should be called after setting the montharray
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min, i);
}

function countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min, i) {
  theyear = yr;
  themonth = m;
  theday = d;
  thehour = hr;
  theminute = min;
  var today = new Date();
  var todayy = today.getYear();
  if (todayy < 1000) {
    todayy += 1900;
  }
  var todaym = today.getMonth();
  var todayd = today.getDate();
  var todayh = today.getHours();
  var todaymin = today.getMinutes();
  var todaysec = today.getSeconds();
  var todaystring1 = montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy + " " + todayh + ":" + todaymin + ":" + todaysec;
  var todaystring = Date.parse(todaystring1) + (tz * 1000 * 60 * 60);
  var futurestring1 = (montharray[m - 1] + " " + d + ", " + yr + " " + hr + ":" + min);
  var futurestring = Date.parse(futurestring1) - (today.getTimezoneOffset() * (1000 * 60));
  var dd = futurestring - todaystring;
  var dday = Math.floor(dd / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1);
  var dhour = Math.floor((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 1000) * 1);
  var dmin = Math.floor(((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
  var dsec = Math.floor((((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

  //need to target the elements using i in the id
  document.getElementById('dday' + i).innerHTML = dday;
  document.getElementById('dhour' + i).innerHTML = dhour;
  document.getElementById('dmin' + i).innerHTML = dmin;
  document.getElementById('dsec' + i).innerHTML = dsec;

  //need to pass the parameter as passed to this function
  setTimeout(countdown.bind(this, yr, m, d, hr, min, i), 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="listinglist"></div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible that this code will accept 4 different timers? So far they are all the same. I thought the second loop would do that but it doesn't so far.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. However If I have different numbers for the year, month and date won't I need the loop?

Comment: In the place where I create my table, I actually read from an xml file. That is then placed into the table as well. The loop in the table creation area was meant to load each entry of the xml as well.

Comment: @JianYA then you need to use a loop, but the values to be passed should come from the xml values

Comment: Is this the same loop I used in my original code? @arun-p-johny